# backtracking for graph with adj list

Tags: algorithm, graph-coloring

Consider a graph with adjacency list as  given below and with 4 vertices and 4 edges.

```
  1 2 3 4
1 0 1 0 1
2 1 0 1 0
3 0 1 0 1
4 1 0 1 0
```

It is a simple rectangular graph.

In m-colorability graph problem we have to colour the graph with no adjacent nodes of the same color.I am reading a book which says that if the degree of the graph is 'd' then graph can be colored in d+1 ways.But the above graph can be colored in 2 ways which is the degree of the graph.How?

Comment: 1. what do you mean by *the degree of the graph*? As far as I know only vertices have degrees not graphs. (do you mean minimal degree?) 2. you ask about ways of coloring your graph? or minimal numbers of colors needed to color it?

Comment: moreover what is the book? and what **exactly** it says? your graph is clearly colorable with just 2 colors.

Answer (score 0):

If graph is fully connected then the graph is colorable with d+1 color. In this case it is not fully connected so colors can be less than d+1 which is 3 here and as seen it is 2 in this case.

**Note:** fully connected means all vertices are connected to each other directly by edge.